# Assign value to a DataGridViewComboBoxColum column

Tags: c#, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

With a code like similar :

```
gridNomiColonne.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = value
```

i cannot assign a value to a DataGridViewComboBoxColum.
How can I do it?

Thanks in advance,
Simone

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
cboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.